# Alamofire download to file system doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsfilemanager

I'm creating a test project before we implement the Alamofire downloading into our app. Right now, I'm facing a strange issue and maybe I don't understand how Alamofire Download or the `FileManager` works.

I simply download 3 files from a URL and want to store them in the file system. After that, I want to use them as local data in a WKWebView (not implemented yet).

This is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func loadWebsite(_ sender: Any) {     
        NetworkService.shared.getFile(path: "webview.html", completion: {
            NetworkService.shared.getFile(path: "css/style.css", completion: {
                NetworkService.shared.getFile(path: "images/square.jpg", completion: {
                    self.fillInContent()
                })
            })
        })
    }

    private func fillInContent() {
        let documentURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let fileUrl = documentURL.appendingPathComponent("webview.html")

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileUrl.absoluteString) {
            print("True")
        } else {
            print("no webview")
        }
    }
}
```

I know the code for loading the resources isn't written very well with starting a new request in the completion block, but again it's just a test project.

This is my NetworkService singleton:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class NetworkService {
    static let shared = NetworkService()

    // Thread-safe
    private init() {}

    func getFile(path: String, completion: @escaping() -> Void) {
        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = {_, _ in
            let documentURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let fileURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent(path)

            return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }

        Alamofire.download("https://myurl.com/" + path, to: destination)
            .responseData { response in
                if let error = response.result.error {
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }

               completion()
        }
    }
}
```

When I print out the file URLs in the NetworkService or the `fillInContent()` in the VC they are correct. However, the `fillInContent()` method always prints out "no webview". So the file doesn't exist. I expected it to be overwritten by the other completion blocks, but even if I start the function right in the completion block the `fileExist()` also returns false. Even if I remove the other 2 calls to `getFile()` I won't get true for fileExists here.

**Current behavior:** I get "no webview" all the time.

**Expected behavior:** The `fillInContent()` method prints out "True".

Any help or guidance is highly appreciated!

**EDIT:** After running the project twice, I also receive this error message: 'Error: The file “Documents” couldn’t be saved in the folder “1E07C511-B5B3-4B5A-84E1-8EF61F6B7340” because a file with the same name already exists.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this method to get documents directory:

```
try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                             in: .userDomainMask,
                             appropriateFor: nil,
                             create: true)
```

And use `fileUrl.path` instead of `fileUrl.absoluteString`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's still the same result :/

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Hmm, now the code to get the documents directory in the getFile() returns nil.

Comment: I edited my question. I suspect that error to cause most of the trouble as I don't even receive data from the request (as an error occurs). However, I don't know what "Documents" file is meant with that.

Comment: I guess changing fileUrl.absoluteString to fileUrl.path solved my problem.